# Trouble with getElementByID on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this code to get the `ClientId`

```
"<%=ddlClienteSuc.ClientID%>"
```

and it returns this:

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlClienteSuc
```

and doesn't function with `getElementById`

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlClienteSuc")
```

this works:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlClienteSuc")
```

what can I do? Please help me.

Comment: The `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlClienteSuc` is looks like the name o f the control and the `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlClienteSuc` the ID. For me you say them different. the `"<%=ddlClienteSuc.ClientID%>"` is working and is the ID, maybe you try to find it by the name, or you have doublicate ids on the same page ?. This is trick question :) Its work as it is, you have some other error.

Comment: please show the line in javascript that is giving you the problem since it does not seem the asp.net part is wrong, ddClienteSuc.ClientId should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set ClientIDMode="Static" and you should get back ddlClienteSuc instead of
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlClienteSuc

Comment: thanks but i had migrated from net framework 2.0 and have around 50 pages there is'n another way ???

Comment: i changed ClientIDMode to "Static"  but this "<%=ddlClienteSuc.ClientID%>" is stilll returning  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlClienteSuc" what i doing grong please help me thanks :)